# PhpStorm not commenting blade correctly

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-blade

Im having problems at the moment because PhpStorm 2020.3 is using `<!--  -->` this way to comment when i use a block comment, instead of `{{-- --}}` in blade files

Comment: Hmm .. works fine for me here. Please provide screenshots of the whole IDE window (maybe there is something wrong with the Blade files. Also: try with all custom (not bundled by default) plugins disabled (in case if some another plugin interferes)

Comment: P.S. For ref purposes: the same on PhpStorm Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010183760-PhpStorm-not-commenting-blade-correctly

Comment: Can't reproduce this either. Probably this is caused by a file structure. You might want to share the file for us to take a look